# Game Loop on Server

Tags: game-loop, server

I'm writing a simple mobile game with the following requirements:

1. Server needs to update all active games at frequent and regular interval (i.e. I need a game loop running on a server but the update frequency can be as low as 1 second or more)
2. Update doesn't need to be exactly timed, but needs to be consistent (i.e. it's fine if the updates happen at 1 second give or take 0.5 seconds, but they can't take 5 seconds)
3. The ability to scale is nice but not necessary. I don't expect more than a few hundred games running simultaneously, so it's fine if the server doesn't handle a bajillion simultaneous requests.
4. Relatively limited configuration/maintenance costs. I've set up some basic systems and SSH'ed into my share of servers, but I'm not an expert in server-side technologies and can't find the time to become one. Basically, I need something that allows me to spend most of my time writing code and not configuration files.

So my questions are:

1. Are there any PaaS services that can be used to do this? (I've looked into Google App Engine and Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk but both have serious issues, but I'm happy to be convinced otherwise or be pointed towards a similar service)
2. If not are there any libraries designed for simple game servers that are relatively simple to deploy on a basic LAMP stack (or equivalent)?

Comment: worker threads + delayqueues (assuming each game is fully independent)

Comment: the simplest solution is to write your own server code and put it on your own box. You can even rent dedicated hardware to run your server console on. You won't be able to get consistent timings with a virtualized server

Comment: I think this is a great question, and I would love to contribute and hear the community thoughts on this :(